# Bisecting an array of objects: are not all of them enumerated?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bisection

This is my bisector:

```
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d: any) {
  console.log('d date ', d.date);
  return d.date;
}).left;
```

I have array of dates(78 total) but on my bisector it's only logging 5 like below repeatedly?

```
timesDataPath  (78) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, ...]
App.tsx:122 d date  Mon Aug 12 2019 12:45:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
App.tsx:122 d date  Mon Aug 12 2019 11:05:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
App.tsx:122 d date  Mon Aug 12 2019 10:15:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
App.tsx:122 d date  Mon Aug 12 2019 09:50:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
App.tsx:122 d date  Mon Aug 12 2019 09:40:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
App.tsx:122 d date  Mon Aug 12 2019 09:35:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)
```

How could this happen? My object in the array is like this:

```
{
  1. open: "25891.8496"
  2. high: "25896.8809"
  3. low: "25890.6797"
  4. close: "25893.1504"
  5. volume: "3205446"
  date: Mon Aug 12 2019 16:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time) {}
}
```

This is how i use it:

```
.on('mousemove', function() {
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    var mouseDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]);
    var i = bisectDate(timesDataPath, mouseDate);
```

`timesDataPath` is what I use for x axis and y axis and I have no problems with the graph, just making this part for the pointer don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **expected behaviour**.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/e3d311c7d5881e4dae81f5fccd794760fe99efe1/src/bisector.js#L9) for `d3.bisector`, you'll see that it does not iterate the whole array the way you think. Have a look here:

```
while (lo < hi) {
    var mid = lo + hi >>> 1;
    if (compare(a[mid], x) > 0) hi = mid;
    else lo = mid + 1;
}
```

The interesting part lies here: `var mid = lo + hi >>> 1;`. What this bitwise  (named [zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_(Zero-fill_right_shift))) does is calculating the **midpoint** of the array.

In your case, the array has 78 elements. Therefore:

```js
console.log(0 + 78 >>> 1)
```

And it keeps getting the midpoint of the remaining part, again and again, until finding the element. Have a look here:

```js
let lo = 0,
  hi = 78;
while (lo < hi) {
  let mid = lo + hi >>> 1;
  console.log(mid)
 lo = mid + 1;
}
```

For an array of 78 elements it does that 6 times (not 5, as you mentioned), and that's why you see the `console.log` working only 6 times.

Have a look at this demo, an array of 78 elements, the `console.log` works 7 times:

```js
const data = d3.range(78);

const bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  return d;
}).left;

bisect(data, 5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now let's increase the array to 1000 elements. The `console.log` works 10 times:

```js
const data = d3.range(1000);

const bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  return d;
}).left;

bisect(data, 5);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but how is it not working as expected? i am looking at this sample http://bl.ocks.org/mikehadlow/93b471e569e31af07cd3?fbclid=IwAR3YoTiCbXbCloa1mIdm6HK01zHXQyR93g5rjnLCWJBspH7Zkl5g7zOqLdw, i was hopng it return the index

Comment: Is this really the first thing you say to someone that tried to help you? Again, the `console.log` is working as expected. There is nothing more I can explain here.

Comment: thanks, i was looking at the version and the link is at 3.x and i am using 5.x, i was looking at docs and can't think of difference, i wish i could see this sample in version 5.x

Comment: hey this maybe alot to ask but i hope maybe you can change this sample http://bl.ocks.org/mikehadlow/93b471e569e31af07cd3?fbclid=IwAR3YoTiCbXbCloa1mIdm6HK01zHXQyR93g5rjnLCWJBspH7Zkl5g7zOqLdw to version 5.7.x i have been stuck for day, i'm not good enough :(

Comment: Apparently you asked the wrong question here: if you read your question again, you'll see that you're asking why the console works only half-dozen times, despite your array having 78 elements. And I answered that, but clearly that's **not** your problem. So, please post a new question, explaining **exactly** what is your problem and what is not working, with all the relevant details. Try to be concise and clear.